# How to burn MP3 files to a CD without going through iTunes on a Macbook?

Tags: mac, itunes, mp3

I would like to just be able to click and drag files from my hard disk to the CD and then click "burn". I have not figured out how to do this. When I click and drag it gives me a direct access icon, but not a file. What am I doing wrong? Going through iTunes is clunky and very time consuming.

Comment: Are you wanting data MP3s (not all devices can play these) or an audio CD? If 1) you used to be able to make a 'burn folder' (right click on the desktop) otherwise, iTunes may sadly be the easiest option.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you're trying to burn audio files (MP3 / FLAC / AAC / etc.) without encoding them into the 16-bit PCM Linear 44.1 khz format that is required by the Compact Disc Digital Audio device.  As clunky as iTunes is, it will be, more or less, time consuming no matter what other process you choose because that encoding **needs** to happen.

That being said, there is a "lightweight" application that is recommended that will turn your digital audio files and turn them into a proper audio CD:

- [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)

Comment: Assuming the OP doesn't want an MP3 data disc, this seems right on target. In either case, Burn is a great alternative.